# Vim OmniComplete for D

Tags: vim, d, omnicomplete

Is there any Vim plugin that provide completition for D using OmniComplete? I have searched over Google but I found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [syntax based omnicompletion](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ft-syntax-omni), which should work as long as you have a working syntax file.

Vim should already come with a syntax file from D, starting from version 6.3 or later. If you are using an earlier version of Vim you could try [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=379).

Answer (score 1):

You should try https://github.com/idanarye/vim-dutyl
It provides auto-complete, goto-def, show document.